# Create a Zip Archive from a cloned GitHub repo in Python

Tags: python, django, git, zip

I'm working on a project using python(3.6) in which I need to create a zip archive which includes all files from a GitHub repo. The user will provide the git repo URL then I will need to clone this repo and create a zip archive which includes all files from GitHub repo.

Here's what I have tried:

```
                ARCHIVE_NAME = func_obj.fname + '.zip'
                zip_archive = zipfile.ZipFile(ARCHIVE_NAME, "w")
                # Write files to the archive
                zip_archive.write(git.Repo.clone_from(func_obj.sc_github, to_path=os.path.join(ARCHIVE_NAME)))
                zip_archive.close()
                file_path = os.path.join(IGui.settings.BASE_DIR, ARCHIVE_NAME)
```

> Here's the updated code, which cloned the repo and generates the zip archive but it has another problem as describes below:

```
                ARCHIVE_NAME = func_obj.fname + '.zip'
                zip_archive = zipfile.ZipFile(ARCHIVE_NAME, "w")
                # Write files to the archive
                tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
                # Ensure the file is read/write by the creator only
                saved_umask = os.umask(0o077)
                temppath = os.path.join(tempdir)
                print(temppath)
                git.Repo.clone_from(func_obj.sc_github, to_path=temppath)
                dirList = os.listdir(temppath)
                for file in dirList:
                    get_file = str(os.path.join(temppath, file))
                    print(get_file)
                    zip_archive.write(get_file)
                os.umask(saved_umask)
                shutil.rmtree(tempdir)
```

> Problem is: **
>   for example, if the tempath is: /var/folders/lf/pc01_3zj38q0qv1vq9r6rxs00000gn/T/tmpca2fv8eg then the zip archives creates as: when we extract the zip archive it includes var directory, then inside var dir we have folders directory, then inside folders directory we have lf dir and till to the tmpca2fv8eg directory then inside this directory we have our repo files, But I need to have my repo files directly in zip archive when we extract it we get all files, not any directory.**

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what parts doesn't work exactly?

Comment: it returns : `  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 418, in wait
    raise GitCommandError(self.args, status, errstr)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git clone -v https://github.com/arycloud/testing.git hjh.zip
  stderr: 'fatal: destination path 'hjh.zip' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Comment: Well you have to make sure that the file doesn't exist if you want to overwrite it.

Comment: actually, i want to create an archive from cloned repo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative way to create the repository archive is to use the [`git archive` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) which supports `zip` and `tar` formats:

```
import git
import tempfile
import os

tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
temppath = os.path.join(tempdir)
print(temppath)
repo = git.Repo.clone_from(
    'https://github.com/serebrov/nodejs-typescript.git',
    to_path=temppath)

with open("archive.zip", "wb") as zipfile:
    repo.archive(zipfile, format='zip')
```

The resulting `archive.zip` contains the repository files:

```
(venv) $ unzip -l archive.zip 
Archive:  archive.zip
c55ff81ef2934670cb273b5fadd555d932081f2e
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       18  2017-11-10 22:57   .gitignore
      552  2017-11-10 22:57   README.md
        0  2017-11-10 22:57   client/
      305  2017-11-10 22:57   client/client.ts
      146  2017-11-10 22:57   client/tsconfig.json
      586  2017-11-10 22:57   package.json
        0  2017-11-10 22:57   server/
      488  2017-11-10 22:57   server/app.ts
      195  2017-11-10 22:57   server/tsconfig.json
        0  2017-11-10 22:57   views/
      169  2017-11-10 22:57   views/index.html
---------                     -------
     2459                     11 files
```

Comment: In this way it's still creating a folder **archive** inside the zip archive, i need only files directly in zip archives not inside a folder, when we extract the archive, we should get all files directly. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Did you try it? It does not create a folder "archive" inside the zip, the content of the repository is directly inside the archive, see https://imgur.com/a/y1Wm9.

Comment: yes, i have tried as: `tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
                    # Ensure the file is read/write by the creator only
                    saved_umask = os.umask(0o077)
                    temppath = os.path.join(tempdir)
                    print(temppath)
                    repo = git.Repo.clone_from(func_obj.sc_github, to_path=temppath)

                    with open("archive.zip", "wb") as zipfile:
                        repo.archive(zipfile, format='zip')
                    os.umask(saved_umask)
                    shutil.rmtree(tempdir)`

Comment: I don't see how that can create the "archive" folder inside zip, taking into account that `repo.archive` command that does the work knows nothing about the archive file name. The snippet I posted in my answer is fully functional, you can run it and see how it works (because I can test on your code as it is not a complete example I can run).

Comment: your example code also creating archive folder inside zip archive!

Comment: I added `unzip -l archive.zip` output example, also see the image I posted above - there are no any additional folders, just the files from the repo.

Comment: What if you use the different archive name, let's say "test.zip", does it make the folder named "test" inside the archive? Also how do you check if there is a folder in the archive, maybe it's just the tool you use to extract the archive produces it?

Comment: i'm extracting it directly on my mac os x!

Comment: Try using the command line tool such as `unzip archive.zip` or use `unzip -l archive.zip`, I suspect it's just the app you are using creates that top-level folder named same as the archive name.

Comment: Now it's returning another error for the uploaded file name, See this question, please! https://stackoverflow.com/q/47605818/7644562

Comment: Confirmed: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51229/compressed-archive-in-lion-creates-a-root-level-archive-folder-in-zip-file - that' the app you use to extract the archive creates that folder.

Comment: I'm uploading this archive directly to google cloud storage their it's also creating a root directory inside the archive, it should work there also!

Comment: now, it's working with another small tweak, thanks for your help!

Comment: can you take a look at this question, please?     https://stackoverflow.com/q/47605818/7644562

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to save the git repo into the ZipFile directly from the `git.Repo.clone_from` command. This will not work, as the git library cannot save a repo instantly into a zip file. What you'll have to do is choose a temporary path to save the repo onto, and then give that path to `zip_archive.write`.

What you want is:

```
tempPath = "/Users/abdul/temp/temp_zip" # you can change this, this is temporary

git.Repo.clone_from(func_obj.sc_github, to_path=os.path.join(tempPath))

files = os.listdir(tempPath)

for singleFile in files:
    zip_archive.write(os.path.join(tempPath, singleFile), singleFile)

# you can now delete the folder at tempPath
```

Instead of:

```
zip_archive.write(git.Repo.clone_from(func_obj.sc_github, to_path=os.path.join(ARCHIVE_NAME)))
```

A sample output from your git repo (https://github.com/arycloud/sis-testing.git):

[image: Root directory of the zip file]

Note: this is the root directory of the zip file, no directories in between. This is using this exact code:

```
import git, os, zipfile

zip_archive = zipfile.ZipFile("C:\\Users\\Attoa\\Desktop\\testos.zip", "w")

tempPath = "C:\\Users\\Attoa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\temp_zip\\" # you can change this, this is temporary

git.Repo.clone_from("https://github.com/arycloud/sis-testing.git", to_path=os.path.join(tempPath))

files = os.listdir(tempPath)

for singleFile in files:
    zip_archive.write(os.path.join(tempPath, singleFile), singleFile)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried this: `tempPath = os.path.join(IGui.settings.BASE_DIR, 'git_source')
                    git.Repo.clone_from(func_obj.sc_github, to_path=os.path.join(tempPath))
                    zip_archive.write(tempPath)
                    zip_archive.close()` but it doesn't cloned the repo just created folders from Desktop to my project drectory, folder inside another folder then another folder...

Comment: @AbdulRehman I would very much suggest you follow my advice and use `zip_archive.write(tempPath, <github repo name or just a name you like>)` instead of just `zip_archive.write(tempPath)`, but to give more clarification I need to know what `IGui.settings.BASE_DIR` actually is for your code.

Comment: It’s the root directory of my project!

Comment: @AbdulRehman What is the actual problem? What is the value of `tempPath` and where are the random directories being created?

Comment: Repo has been cloned into **git_source** directory but now I need to make a zip file which includes all files from **git_source** directory only files directly zipped not the folder and also I don't know how many files in the **git_source** directory and what are the names? so, how can I add these files to my zip archive with a loop?

Comment: for example, if the temPath is: `/var/folders/lf/pc01_3zj38q0qv1vq9r6rxs00000gn/T/tmpca2fv8eg` then the zip archives creates as:  when we extract the zip archive it includes **var** directory, then inside var dir we have **folders** directory, then inside folders directory we have **if** dir and till to the **tmpca2fv8eg** directory then inside this direcotry we have our repo files, But I need to have my repo files directly in zip archive when we extract it we get all files, not any direcotry.

Comment: @AbdulRehman Ok, in this case for your specific requirements, I'll amend my answer

Comment: now it returns `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/lf/pc01_3zj38q0qv1vq9r6rxs00000gn/T/tmpyfwnl6jqTestFile.txt'`

Comment: Replace `zip_archive.write(tempPath+singleFile, singleFile)` with `zip_archive.write(os.path.join(tempPath, singleFile), singleFile)`

Comment: it's still creating a folder inside archive then write files inside this folder!

Comment: It isn't doing this for me... can you give an example of a git repo you might be using?

Comment: github.com/arycloud/sis-testing.git

Comment: @AbdulRehman I noticed you edited your question, but this is still wrong, as you should pass (for your specific case) TWO arguments to `zip_archive.write()`. The code in your question should read `zip_archive.write(get_file, file)` instead of `zip_archive.write(get_file)`.

Comment: can you take a look at this question, please? stackoverflow.com/q/47605818/7644562

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating the zip file yourself, you can download an archive of the repository directly from GitHub

The URL you need to call 
 is `http://github.com/user/repository/archive/master.zip`

You can do the same with tags and branch names, by replacing master in the URL above with the name of the branch or tag.

Comment: I need to upload it to google cloud storage, it doesn't work to upload as blob.