# How to get the name of uploaded file in Django

Tags: python, django

I have seen some question about it already but these couldn't solve my issue, that's why I'm asking a new question.So, don't mark this as duplicate, please!

Using Python(3.6) & Django(1.10)
I'm trying to get the name of uploaded file, but it returns

> **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'**

Here's what I have tried:
From **models.py**

```
sourceFile = models.FileField(upload_to='archives/', name='sourceFile', blank=True)
```

From **HTML template**:

```
<div class="form-group" hidden id="zipCode">
                    <label class="control-label" style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: black;">Select File</label>
                    <input id="sourceFile" name="sourceFile" type="file" class="file" multiple
                           data-allowed-file-extensions='["zip"]'>
                    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text control-label" style="color:black; font-size: .9rem;">
                        Upload a Tar or Zip
                        archive which include Dockerfile, otherwise your deployment will fail.
                    </small>
                </div>
```

From **views.py**:

```
if form.is_valid():
               func_obj = form
               func_obj.sourceFile = form.cleaned_data['sourceFile']
               func_obj.save()
               print(func_obj.sourceFile.name)
```

what's wrong here?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) might help.

Comment: have you added form enctype as multipart/form-data ?? And have you bound the data properly in the view eg. form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES) ?

Comment: yes, I have setup both of these things (1): **enctype="multipart/form-data"**  (2): `if request.method == 'POST':
            post_data = request.POST.copy()
            post_data.update({'user': request.user.pk})
            form = forms.SlsForm(post_data, request.FILES)`

Comment: Will multiple files be uploaded at a time or just one?

Comment: Only one file will be uploaded!

Comment: can you put all view, model & template code here, that will help us understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To get the filename, you simply use the request.FILES dictionary (I assume that there is only 1 file being uploaded)

Example:

```
try:
    print(next(iter(request.FILES))) # this will print the name of the file
except StopIteration:
    print("No file was uploaded!")
```

Note that this requires that the files were sent as a part of a form by the POST method.

To change their name to a random string, I recommend `uuid.uuid4`, as this generates a random string that is VERY unlikely to collide with anything already there. Also, you need to edit your `upload_to=` section of your `sourceFile` model by providing a function to generate the name:

```
# In models.py

def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    filename = "{}.zip".format(str(uuid.uuid4().hex))
    return os.path.join('archives', filename)

# later....

sourceFile = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, name='sourceFile', blank=True)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it returns : `print(next(iter(request.FILES)))
StopIteration`

Comment: The file was uploaded but there was a problem in my template, i have fixed it, thanks for your help!

Comment: @AbdulRehman If my answer helped, please mark it as correct so that others with the same problem may find it.

Comment: Hi, @Atto Allas ! how we can rename the uploaded file? I need to rename the uploaded zip archive, can you help me? please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman Hi! Do you want to rename it before or after it’s created?

Comment: I need to rename it after upload!

Comment: I will generate a random name which has some characters and number with **.zip** as an extension.